# How to insert python list to particular Oracle database column?

Tags: python-3.x

I am trying to insert a python list to particular oracle database column but i am getting error. Tablename is MSDS_VII and the columns are NO,ITEM,STATUS,STATUS1. You can see the datatype of each column based on the output i have pasted below. Here is what I tried till now. Need guidance!

```
conn = cx_Oracle.connect(conn_str)
c = conn.cursor()
c.execute(u'select NO,ITEM,STATUS,STATUS1 from MSDS_VII')
a=[]
b=[]
e=[]
f=[]
for row in c:
    e.append(row[0])
    f.append(row[1])
    a.append(row[2])
    b.append(row[3])
d=[[k,l,i,j] for k,l,i,j in zip(e,f,a,b)]
print(d)
print("\n")
for i in d:
    if(i[2]==1):
        i[3]="ON"
    elif(i[2]==0):
        i[3]="OFF"
    else:
        i[3]="NULL"
print(d)
for i in d:
    c.execute( 'insert into MSDS_VII(STATUS1 ) values (%s)',i[3])
conn.close()

Output:

[[1, 'item1', 1, None], [2, 'item2', 0, None], [3, 'item3', 1, None], [4, 'item4', 1, None], [5, 
'item5', 0, None]]


[[1, 'item1', 1, 'ON'], [2, 'item2', 0, 'OFF'], [3, 'item3', 1, 'ON'], [4, 'item4', 1, 'ON'], [5, 
'item5', 0, 'OFF']]


Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:/Users/Admin/Desktop/status.py", line 28, in <module>
c.execute( 'insert into MSDS_VII(STATUS1 ) values (%s)',i[3])
cx_Oracle.DatabaseError: ORA-01036: illegal variable name/number
```

[Database description](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cOUzW.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bind variables in Oracle are denoted by a colon followed by a number. Also, values for bind variables should be passed as a tuple:

```
c.execute( 'insert into MSDS_VII(STATUS1 ) values (:1)', (i[3],))
```

Edit: It is now clear that you are only trying to update the existing rows, rather than inserting new rows. You should use the `UPDATE` statement instead:

```
c.execute("update MSDS_VII set STATUS1=decode(STATUS, 1, 'ON', 0, 'OFF', 'NULL')")
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply @blhsing .I tried as suggested by you and i am getting integrity error here due to primary key                                            
 cx_Oracle.IntegrityError: ORA-01400: cannot insert NULL into ("HSM"."MSDS_VII"."NO")

Comment: Then the table must be defined with columns that have no default values, in which case you must insert values for those columns too, not just `STATUS1`. EDIT: Yes, you have to insert a value for `NO` then.

Comment: Please check the image of database i have attached above. I have all the values as required .Just i am trying to fill the STATUS1 column

Comment: I tried what u suggested. It didnt give any error but it didnt modify STATUS1 too..It still remains null @blhsing

Comment: You need to call `conn.commit()` after you perform data manipulations for the transaction to be committed.